# Why isn't an update reflected right away when posting changes to a Rally story via the REST API?

Tags: api, rest, rally

I've noticed when retrieving a story/defect after first updating it, sometimes the retrieve response returns the field values as if the update never happened.  Retrying the retrieve after a short delay (~500ms) returns the updated field values as expected.  Is this a known behaviour?  Is there any way of avoiding this?

I'm using the Rally API 2.0 - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/

The update is being performed using this URI:

```
POST /slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect/14173461229?key=<key> HTTP/1.1
```

I'm retrieving the story after update as follows:

```
GET /slm/webservice/v2.0/artifact?query=(ObjectId%20=%2014173461229)&start=1&pagesize=20&fetch=true HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your integration doing that it needs to re-poll the artifact within < 1 second of POST'ing an update? Is there a second process that does polling that is revealing the latency for the updates? Does your integration run multiple threads? Does the response time vary at all depending on time of day, etc.? There are any number of factors that could be at play here, but 500 ms doesn't seem like an un-reasonable refresh rate given factors such as latency over HTTP/S as well as server-side database and cache updates. That said, for an in-depth look you may wish to inquire with [Rally Support](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/help.sp?pp=contact) (rallysupport@rallydev.com) as they have tools that can help evaluate server-side response time corresponding to requests by specific UserID.

Comment: This behaviour is exposed in a unit test for our Rally client.  We post an update and immediately retrieve the result to verify correct behaviour of our client.  This test is run single-threaded.  We have not measured the response time at different times of day.  I expect the API to behave transactionally; i.e. when an update response returns successfully I expect to be able to see the results via subsequent API calls, however if my expectations are incorrect it would be great to know what the expected behaviour should be.

Comment: I would still recommend checking with Rally Support. They can work with you to review server-side response times.